# How many additional image sizes I can add with add_image_size function?

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, thumbnails

I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1 rus version.

I have custom post types portfolio & slider along with standart posts and pages.

I want to add some additional image sizes to Wordpress for displaying different image thumbnails on website.

So I use this code for adding additional sizes in my functions.php file:

```
    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
       add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
       set_post_thumbnail_size( 315, 315, true ); 
     }

    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
          add_image_size('portfolio-thumbnail',315, 315, true );
        //add_image_size('slider-thumbnail',350, 150, true );
        //add_image_size('slider-single',700, 370, true );
        //add_image_size('portfolio-article-thumbnail',270, 150, true );
        //add_image_size('article-single',700, 370, true );
          add_image_size('portfolio-single-image', 300, 533, false );
        //add_image_size('portfolio-single-gallery', 72, 72, true );
          add_image_size('portfolio-related-projects', 150, 150, true );
        //add_image_size('portfolio-project-article', 500, 400, true );
        //add_image_size('portfolio-project-article2', 700, 500, true );
        //add_image_size('dimal-single-image', 300, 9999 )
    }
```

Now I'd explain why some additional sizes are commented.
When I want to upload a featured image to a standart or custom post i open image uploader, choose a picture and it uploads succesfully. Only if the code stays as it is above.

But if I uncomment even 1 of those other sizes and try to upload the featured image to the post - I get HTTP Error. Image's not being uploaded.

**UPDATE** HTTP Error goes without any error number.

Again, if I comment some of uncommented sizes and leave the new one image uploads succesfully!

After some trials I've founded that only If I leave 3 sizes uncommented in TOTAL - images upload succesfully. If I add even 1 and get 4 sizes in total - images won't upload and I get HTTP Error.

**I must state that problem occurs only when working with big images with resolution bigger than 1280x800.**

So, is there some kind of limit to additional image sizes? What's the problem? I use shared hosting.

**ADDITION**

I tried testing my WP Theme on my local xampp server and everything went well! So I can tell for sure now that problem lies in server settings. I compared my local server settings via phpinfo and my shared hosting server setting via phpinfo. I found these differences in them:

Shared server settings:

- max_execution_time   10  10
- max_file_uploads 128 128
- max_input_nesting_level  64  64
- max_input_time           60  60
- memory_limit         64M 64M
- post_max_size            64M 64M
- upload_max_filesize  64M 64M

Local server settings:

- max_execution_time   30  30
- max_file_uploads 20  20
- max_input_nesting_level  64  64
- max_input_time           60  60
- memory_limit         128M    128M
- post_max_size            64M 64M
- upload_max_filesize  64M 64M

Also, I tried changing memory_limit of local server from 128M to 64M and image uploads still worked well!

**SOLUTION**

Ok, I get the answer from my hoster and they said that error occured because of "Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in script". And suggested to add new max_execution_time value via .htaccess file in public_html folder of my website.

So I added these lines to .htaccess file in my public_html folder:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 30
</IfModule>
```

I decided to add new memory_limit value too, just in case. 
Now everything works well! Thanks to everyone who tried to help me with the issue!

Comment: Did you read the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Yes, from cover to cover. What exactly are you trying to say? I'm not really understand.

Comment: What error exactly you get? Seems bodi0 may be right, there are no limits in number of possible image sizes.

Comment: Yes, I thought myself too that there are no limits in number of additional image sizes. And it seems that problem lies in image resolution. I get just HTTP Error, without any error number. Only with images with resolution bigger than 1280x800 pixels.

Comment: add in wp-config.php define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

Comment: I added that line and checked. Didn't work. Still HTTP Error on images bigger than 1280x800px.

Comment: The setting `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) increases PHP Memory **only** for `WordPress`, not other applications, so you need to change the global memory allocation for PHP scripts, read my comment below my answer.

Comment: True, but it increases memory for worpdress PHP within allocated resources, that's why may help, if not php.ini is right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using large images, it is normal at some point your server to run out of memory, so the error you are receiving is most probably related to that.

Read this post for details https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76915/http-error-when-uploading-images-over-specific-dimensions

Comment: So, if problem lies in memory than only solution is to change memory limit on my server? But I use shared hosting and I don't think they would allow me to those settings. Maybe I can make some changes in wp-config or htaccess for these?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 90% of users worldwide use shared hosting servers. Basically the hosting company provides the user-configurable `php.ini` and `httpd.conf` file (at least my did). Ask your hosting company about this, then - if you can change the configuration files - access those files via FTP (with Filezilla FTP maybe, it is the easiest), make changes, save and done.

Comment: I sent a letter to support. Now still waiting for their reply on the topic. Meanwhile I tested this theme on my local xampp server and everything went well! I compared phpinfo values from my local server and shared hosting server and found some differences. I'd state theme in the topic body.

Comment: This `memory_limit 128M` is the key. It should be as large as possible. This is not the hard drive space limit, if you wonder, but the allocated RAM per script basis. Keep in mind that on your local server you run not as many websites as on your shared host. You do not know how many other websites are there (they may be 20 or 30 in typical case). Anyway, if you manage to fix the problem thanks to my answer here, mark it so other users can find it as useful.

Comment: I posted the final solution in topic body.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you forgot to remove the semicolon at the end of this line?

add_image_size('portfolio-related-projects', 150, 150, true );